# Python_Web_scraping Html Table

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm Python beginner developer, I'm still in the learning phase.
More specifically working on scraping using requests and bs4.
When tried to scrape the following link: 'http://directorybtr.az.gov/listings/FirmSearchResults.asp?Zip%20Like%20%22850%25%22'

I used the following code :

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ="http://directorybtr.az.gov/listings/FirmSearchResults.asp?Zip%20Like%20%22850%25%22"
res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
res.close()
results = soup.find('table')
```

There is no table in results although the table are present when inspecting the source page in Chrome.
Any solution or explanation please?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is rather incomplete. `url` is undefined, neither is `r`.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake 'r' is 'res' so it's defined. and url is the link above , already defined in my code. url='http://directorybtr.az.gov/listings/FirmSearchResults.asp?Zip%20Like%20%22850%25%22'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table data is inside frame, u need to go first

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BASE_URL = "http://directorybtr.az.gov/listings/" 
URL = BASE_URL + "FirmSearchResults.asp?Zip%20Like%20%22850%25%22"
#u need session because the frame use the search results data, u cant directly go to Firms.asp
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
#find the first frame 
frame = soup.find("frame")
#go to the frame link ( Firms.asp )
response = session.get(BASE_URL + frame.attrs['src'])
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find("table")
print table
response.close()
```